# In an excel pivot table, how do calculate percentages within a row of items within that row?

Tags: excel, excel-pivot

I am not trying to calculate a percentage as a percentage of the grand total. Rather I am trying to figure out what percentage of items within a specific row (or grouped category) meet a certain criterion. In this case, people who met the criterion are marked with a "1" and people who did not meet the criterion are marked with a "0".

For example:

```
AgencyName  PersonName  MetCriterion?
----------  ----------  -------------
Acme        Person A    1
Acme        Person B    0
Acme        Person C    1
Acme        Person D    1
Betas       Person E    1
Betas       Person F    0
```

Desired Output:

```
AgencyName  % Who Met Criterion
----------  -------------------
Acme        75%
Betas       50%
```

One way to do this would be to calculate =Sum(MetCriterion)/Count(MetCriterion), but I do not think that is possible.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Average of" calculation for the target column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you put the agency name in the D column and the data is stored A:C you could try

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"=" & D1,C:C) / SUM(C:C)
```

Edit: I misread the question the above takes the percent of everyone that passed below takes the correct percentage

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"=" & D1,C:C) / COUNTIF(A:A, "=" & D1)
```

Edit2: Realizing this is just

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,"=" & D1,C:C)
```

which is what I'm assuming you meant by "average of"

Comment: Thank you for attempting to answer my question. I'm not sure how to use the formulas you listed. Where is the formula meant to go? In the original tab with the data or used somehow in the pivot table?

Comment: Oh apologies, this would have to be for the original data where Column A houses all of the agency names, Column C has the meet Criterion Values and D1 has the specific agency you're looking at

Comment: I got that to work. It's not as elegant as the pivot solution I figured out on my own, but CountIf and SumIf are powerful tools, and it's good to know how to use them. Thanks!
A point of confusion for me, was I thought you mean to repeat the agency name for each row, but you mean to only include each agency name once - to in effect build my own pivot. If I had a large number of agencies, I would need to have a function that would enumerate the distinct list "agency name" values. Pivots give you this for free.